# Ternary Logic PHP on Radio Button

Tags: php

I have a form that i pull data from the database and fill in all the fields for a user to edit an existing record. It looks like this currently to set the radio button:

```
<input type="radio" id="statusActive" value="1" name="status" <?php if ($departmentData->thresholdActive == "1"){ echo 'checked'; }else{ echo ''; } ?>> Active
```

What would be the Ternary Logic approach to say:

If POST is true, us the post data else use the one from the database?

Comment: what the point of using ternary operator if you only got one action (`echo '';` makes no effect)? User regular `if()`

Comment: So lets say Choice A is marked in the database. When I pull it, i want to precheck choice A. However, if I select choice B but dont fill out another field, its going to need to keep all the post data so i dont have to fill it all out again

Comment: With radio buttons, only one from a group should be set. It seems to me that you are really asking how to have a default value for the set of radio it tons (from a database) and override that with the contents of a POST variable if present. If so then I recommend rewording the question. You are after an effect, not a specific method (it is called [the XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem))

Answer (score 4):

```
<input type="radio" 
       id="statusActive" 
       value="1" 
       name="status" 
       <?php echo ($departmentData->thresholdActive == "1") ? 'checked' : ''; ?>
>
```

Comment: perfect execution we need to mention echo in radio button :-)

Answer (score 0):

A ternary expression using the following

```
if ($departmentData->thresholdActive == "1")
{ 
    echo 'checked'; 
}
else
{  
    echo ''; 
}
```

Would be

```
echo $departmentData->thresholdActive == "1" ? 'checked' : '';
```

Answer (score 0):

"Ternary logic" - you probably want

```
<?php echo ($departmentData->thresholdActive == "1")? 'checked':'';?>
```

But if you first want to check whether POST is true, it would be cleaner to so something like

```
(isset($_POST))?$_POST['index'] : $dbValue;
```

Where `'index'` refers to a specific post variable (which I assume is present when `POST` is set; you didn't specify whether to check for a *specific* POST variable so it's hard to guess); and assumes that you know how to set `$dbValue` with a "value from the database"